# How to deploy a Eclipse Java Web Dynamic Project on Amazon EC2?

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I'm trying to create a web project that is able to communicate with Amazon RDS. I know how to make a localhost project connect to a RDS with JDBC.

However, the problem is that I never tried to deploy my project (so that, for example someone can type `somePage.com`, and go to my webpage).

I have an **Amazon EC2 instance**, and I've already written a simple hello world jsp page. I am able to compile it and run the **Eclipse Web Dynamic Project** using the installed **Apache Tomcat Server**, and then typing `localhost:8080/somePage` then I can see my hello world popping up.

However, how do I deploy my project on this EC2 instance? I'm using Windows Server 2012 edition.

My whole idea is that once I have one AMI image all setup, then I can just use autoscale to scale my webpage with that AMI image.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: This simple hello world you talk about, where you ran it? In your eclipse? Also, have you installed an Apache Tomcat in your Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, I ran this in my Eclipse. I have not installed Apache Tomcat in my Amazon EC2 instance yet, I think that's the first step to go? I've actually went to that site, but there isn't a EXE file in the zip files. Edit: I just found it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. **Setup Apache Tomcat on your Amazon EC2 instance.**

   - Usually all you have to do is [download the current version](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), unzip it, and start it by running `apache-tomcat-folder\bin\startup.bat`. (You can also donwload an installer and set it up as windows service. Check [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) for more details).
   - Make sure you test it before continuing (open its address on a browser, something like `http://yourinstaceaddress.com:8080/`).
2. **Export your web application `.war` file**

   - In Eclipse, right click on a Web project and select Export. Then select WAR file in the Export window and then select Next. Choose the project, the `.war` file name and folder to export. More detailed explanation can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twcrewar.html) and [here (with pictures)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/j2ee/scenarios/px_testplan/px_export.html).
3. **Deploy the `.war` file to your Tomcat Server**

   - The, by far, simplest way to do this is to place your `.war` (say `myapp.war`) file in your `apache-tomcat-folder\webapps\` folder.
   - There are other ways, like via [Tomcat Manager](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/3_1_x/installation-guide/deploying-on-tomcat#TOC-Using-the-Tomcat-Web-Application-Ma). But they can be tricky and, as a new user, you should avoid them. (Don't worry: the simple method is ok for production deployment).
4. **Test your web app**

   - Visit the url: say your `.war`'s name was `myapp.war`. You should visit `http://yourinstaceaddress.com:8080/myapp`

That's it. If you ever edit the app, repeat steps 2-4 (but delete the `webapps\myapp\` folder created before executing step 3).

Comment: Thanks for your help, It works, woohoo! Is it possible to change myapp to index so that wwww.yourinstanceaddrss.com would work?

Comment: Actually I tried connecting to localhost/myapp, and it works, but when I tried to connect it to instance-public-dns.com/mypass it doesn't. Can it be a firewall issue? Edit: Fixed, I went to firewall and set a all allow inbound policy for all ports.

Comment: Yes, rename `myapp.war` to `ROOT.war` and deploy as usual (don't forget to delete `ROOT.war` and `webapps\ROOT` folder before that).

Comment: @user1157751 Yes, it can. Have you changed the port from the default 8080? Make sure you are hitting the correct port with your browser. Also you can [check if the port is open](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to make sure you can (network-wise) reach the your instance.

Comment: @user1157751 Great! You are faster than I can type :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have one more question, If I set the Apache Tomcat as automatic startup, can I create an image of this EC2 instance and use Elastic Load Balancer between two instances? Would this approach work?

Comment: @user1157751 Also, as a final point, you don't know already, you can change the port from 8080 to 80. If you need any help doing that, let me know and I'll add to the answer how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to port 80 already, so I don't need to type 8080. there is an executable exe file on apache tomcat's download page.

Comment: @user1157751 Yes, I believe it would work. Test your app a bit, though, as it may have issues with concurrent access (or maybe the database).

Comment: Thank you very much with your help. I was looking for answers on how to do this, but many websites uses elastic beanstalk instead. BTW I've never dealt with concurrent access. I think you helped me enough already, I'll try to figure it out! THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com) does exactly what you want.

For you Java web application you literally only have to execute:

```
boxfuse create my-tomcat-app -apptype=load-balanced
boxfuse scale my-tomcat-app -capacity=1-16:t2-micro:cpu25-75
boxfuse run my-tomcat-app-1.0.war -env=prod
```

This will

1. Configure your application to use an ELB
2. Set it to autoscale between 1 and 16 t2.micro instances based on CPU usage (scale in at 25% and below, scale out at 75% and above)
3. Create AMI containg Tomcat and your application ready to boot
4. Create an ELB
5. Create a security group with the correct ports
6. Create an auto-scaling group
7. Launch your instance(s)

Any subsequent update will be done as a zero downtime blue/green deployment.

For your domain, you can simply map your samepage.com DNS record to the CNAME of the ELB.

More info: https://boxfuse.com/blog/auto-scaling