# Eclipse Dynamic Web Project Auto Deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Whenever I am modifying code into eclipse it should automatically get deployed to the tomcat server. It doesn't happen even after server restart. Any suggestions?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How to get our project automatically deployed into the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996741/how-to-deploy-a-eclipse-java-web-dynamic-project-on-amazon-ec2) post for initial application setup. If you don't see your changes right click on Server (Tomcat VX.X server at...) and click on Publish which basically deploys the updates project in the web server instance

[image]